# Do not highlight List Box item till Mouse Up

Tags: delphi, scroll, listbox, firemonkey

I am trying to achieve scrolling effect using Mouse down and Mouse Up by calculating the change in Y Axis values. I could achieve it.
But when I click and drag my mouse cursor, the items that come under mouse cursor show as selected on UI. I mean they get highlighted.
Does any body has an idea to stop showing item highlighted? 
Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the scrollbar/mouse roller? It is not a good practice to try to override the basic functionality of base components!

Comment: It appears OP is trying to implement swipe-up swipe-down functionality similar to the one we are used from mobile devices. And based on the fact that.that various controls gets highlighted during its swipe action I'm guessing that he doesn't scroll his form util MouseUp event is fired.

Comment: You should show us example of your code so that we can see what approach are you using and therefore suggest on what needs to be fixed in order for the code to work as you imagined. That is if it is possible to achieve this using your approach. Right now all we can do is just guessing on what is wrong. So please edit your question accordingly.